# Route to a different controller when a user is signed in using omniauth in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

How do you route to a different controller and page when a user is signed in using Omniauth (no devise) and rails 4?

Current my code is:

```
root to: 'dashboards#home', :constraints => lambda{|req| !req.session[:user_id].blank?}
root to: 'visitors#home'
```

And I get the error:

"Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming."

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the view:

```
<% if signed_in? %>
   <%= render 'dashboards/home' %>
<% else %>
   ...whatever the non-signed in person sees
<% end %>
```

Then you only have one root that can lead to two different pages whether the user is logged in or not.

```
root to: 'vistors#home'
match '/dashboard',   to: 'dashboards#home', via: 'get
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually just do this in the controller. For example, root all to dashboard:

```
root to: 'dashboards#home'
```

Then in the DashboardController:

```
def home
  if session[:user_id].blank?
    redirect_to controller: 'visitors', action: 'home'
  end
end
```

I haven't found a graceful way to do conditional routing in rails, unfortunately.